# Eigenvalues of a skew symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Note: I already know this question has been already answered here many times, but I think I am missing something. Here is part of the proof... the proof is not complete, but I would know how to proceed if only I understood the last part.

Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $A$ and let $x$ be an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$. That is, we have

\begin{align*}
Ax &=\lambda x\\
\bar{x}^{T}Ax&=\lambda \bar{x}^{T} x\\
(Ax)^{T}\bar{x}&=\lambda \|x \|^{2}
\end{align*}

I am wondering about the last line (the left hand side), how is $\bar{x}^{T}Ax=(Ax)^{T}\bar{x}$? I do get the part where $\bar{x}^{T}x=x^{T}\bar{x}$, but what I don't get is why $A=A^{T}$? I know this is only true when the matrix is symmetric. I guess there is something I did not understand quite well, the book I am using solved this problem with a different approach, and I was looking for other ways, and I stumbled upon this one, but as I mentioned I don't quite understand the last part and would appreciate some help.

Comment: As $A$ is skew symmetric then $A=-A^T$.

Comment: I think $\|x^2\|$ should be $\|x\|^2$.

Comment: @AnginaSeng Yes, it was a mistake, I fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $u$ and $v$ are column vectors of the same size then $u^Tv$ is a $1$ by $1$ matrix
which we can think of as a scalar. Taking transposes, since $u^Tv$ is $1$ by $1$, it's
its own transpose, so
$$u^T v=(u^T v)^T=v^T(u^T)^T=v^Tu.$$

Here, take $u=\bar x$ and $v=Ax$. Then
$$\bar x^T(Ax)=(Ax)^T\bar x.$$